# How do we implement method cache in java

Tags: java, spring-aop

I'd like to design my own annotation in order to cache results retrieved from an earlier database call.

For example:

```
public class CountryService {
 @MethodCache
 public List<Country> getCountries();

 @MethodCache
 public Country getCountryById(int countryId);

 @InvalidateMethodCache
 public Country getCountryById(int countryId);

}
```

I want to use this type of annotation for more/all of my methods. What do I need to implement this type of annotation?

@MethodCache: Cache the method result.
@InvalidateMethodCache: Clear the cache.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: When i use this annotation at any method it will cache the method result for application, next time when i will call this method with the same parameters it will not call DB , load from cache.

Comment: If you're looking to create a custom annotation, here are a couple resources http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/ and http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/java-annotations-tutorial.html

Comment: You should probably use existing solutions described in [this](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/03/cacheable-java-annotation.html) article. Please read about [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to be able to implement it you need.

Comment: Spring already comes with [this kind of feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) - either use this, or get inspired on how Spring did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented method cache using spring/java..

https://github.com/vikashnitk50/spring-application-caching/

Answer (score 2):

A solution when using spring-aop is to create an aspect to handle all methods annotated with your custom annotation. An crude implementation would look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> methodCache = new HahsMap<>();

@Around("execution(@(@com.mypack.MethodCache *) *)")
public Object cacheMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
     String cacheKey = getCacheKey(pjp);
     if ( methodCache.get(cacheKey)) {
          return methodCache.get(cacheKey);
     } else {
          Object result = pjp.proceed();
          methodCache.put(cacheKey, result);
          return result;
     }
}

private String getCacheKey(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
     return pjp.getSignature().toString() + pjp.getTarget() + Arrays.asList(pjp.getArgs());
}
```

Comment: If I may add a few suggestions... 1) Don't use a `HashMap`, use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead, so that the cache supports concurrent requests. 2) Make this concurrent map be a Spring bean by means of the @Bean annotation. 3) Autowire this map to the class that contains the @Around method (you'd need this class to be a Spring bean as well).

Answer (score 2):

Well if have ready available annotaions,Better use them

While you can follow this, I hope this guides you

- Implement the interface **CacheAnnotationParser**
- extend **AnnotationCacheOperationSource** so that you put your own **CacheAnnotationParser** in addition to Spring one in the internal parsers collection
- Define your custom **AnnotationCacheOperationSource** to use the same id as Spring one does, so it will override Spring internal. If id matches, it should override Spring one cleanly.

  **Like this**:

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this functionality and uploaded my project in [GITHUB](https://github.com/vikashnitk50/spring-application-caching).

Example:

```
public class CountryService {

    @MethodCache

    public List<Country> getCountries();


    @MethodCache

    public Country getCountryById(int countryId);

    @InvalidateMethodCache

    public Country deleteCountryByID(int countryId);

  }
```